# Flask api hosted as a docker container works with localhost:5000 but not with 172.17.0.2:5000

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerfile

I have created a flask api and hosted it as a docker image. The dockerfile of the image looks like this:

```
FROM pymesh/pymesh:latest

WORKDIR /apiapp

RUN pip install flask

EXPOSE 5000

COPY . /apiapp
ENV FLASK_APP=feature_extract_api.py
# ENTRYPOINT ['/bin/bash']

CMD ["flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

The `app.run()` inside the original python file looks like this:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

The terminal while running the docker container shows this:

```
(dockerenv) D:\Siemens\Docker Pymesh API>docker run -p 5000:5000 pymeshapi:trial  
 * Serving Flask app 'feature_extract_api.py' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://172.17.0.2:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

However, when I go to the link http://172.17.0.2:5000/, I get no response. But when I run
http://localhost:5000/, I get a valid response.

Why is this happening?
Thank You

Comment: Yes, although I didnt completely understand it, but I get the gist. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'trick' with using the bridge network IP address doesn't work on Windows, due to how it runs Docker.

The recommended way is to map the port and use `localhost`.

Comment: So then to call the API I will have to use the link localhost:5000 due to some windows issue?

Comment: Yes. You have to do it that way. But it's also the 'correct' way to do it, so it's not a bad thing.